# Error when submitting formspree.io from GitHub pages

Tags: html, forms, github

I am hosting a website on GitHub pages, and when I try to submit a formspree.io form I get the following error:

[image: error]

Here is my code:

```
<form action="http://formspree.io/example@example.com" method="post">
  <div class="row uniform collapse-at-2">
   <div class="6u">
    <input type="text" name="_replyto" placeholder="Email">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="12u">
   <textarea name="Message" placeholder="Message..." rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="500"></textarea>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div style="display:none">
   <input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="New submission!">
   <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="thanks.html">
   <input type="text" name="_gotcha">
  </div>
  <div class="row uniform">
   <div class="12u">
    <ul class="actions">
     <li>
      <input type="submit" class="special" value="Send">
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </form>
```

Would this be due to a code error, GitHub pages error, or a formspree error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Things you should do to make it work are as follows:

- According to [formspree](https://formspree.io/) example:

```html
<form method="POST" action="http://formspree.io/YOUREMAILHERE">
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email">
  <br>
  <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Here put **your email** in "http://formspree.io/YOUREMAILHERE" after /. And if you want change `name="email"` to `name="_replyto"` this will change the senders email to a clickable link.(Helps while reading in mail)

- If that also doesn't work and it shows that "you must use server. Formspree will not work in pages browsed as HTML pages."

Then inside your `<head>` tag put:

`<meta name="referrer" content="origin">`

Hope it works!!

All the best :)

Comment: I had just removed my email because spam, but the referrer thing worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same problem - add the following to your  field:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="origin" />
```

This worked from me.