# Why doesn't "formspree" submit the messages in github?

Tags: forms, github

I have made a contact form and have uploaded it on github. As the page is completely static, I decided to use `formspree` to submit the comments. But, the messages are not forwarded to my gmail account.

Here is the link to the page: [serrim.github.io](http://serrim.github.io).

Any suggestion is highly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when submitting formspree.io from GitHub pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236643/error-when-submitting-formspree-io-from-github-pages)

Answer (score 1):

The form `action` must be `https://formspree.io/your@email.com`

You have `//your@email.com`

Comment: No, that is not the problem