# Can't submit form with formsubmit.co AJAX API

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch, form-submit, contact-form

I have a Next.js project and I want to be able to submit a contact form to send and email, and I found the [formsubmit.co](https://formsubmit.co/) service that does exactly that. I inserted a contact form in my project and just added `action="https://formsubmit.co/your@email.com" method="POST"` to the `form` tag, as in their example, and it works.

Then I wanted to do some validation on the fields of the form, and I implemented that with Formik, so I had to submit the form with JavaScript. I found the following example of the [formsubmit.io AJAX API](https://formsubmit.co/ajax-documentation):

```js
fetch("https://formsubmit.co/ajax/your@email.com", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        name: "FormSubmit",
        message: "I'm from Devro LABS"
    })
})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

but I get the following response:

```json
{
  success: "false",
  message: "Make sure you open this page through a web server, FormSubmit will not work in pages browsed as HTML files."
}
```

I opened a JavaScript console in [formsubmit.co](https://formsubmit.co/) website and ran that code from there and it works. I have tried with the console in other websites like Google, stackoverflow, etc, but I get the same bad response I get in my project.

I found some [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236643/error-when-submitting-formspree-io-from-github-pages) where people suggest to add `<meta name="referrer" content="origin" />` to the `head` tag, but it doesn't work for me.

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to get it to work? Or if there is another service with which I can do the same? My project is a static website, so I wouldn't want to have to make a backend just to send emails from a contact form.

Comment: _The form was submitted successfully._ This is a problem for your requirements? Could you explain further?

Comment: Sorry, I actually pasted the response I get when I make the request from the formsubmit.io website. My mistake. I edited the post.

Comment: Thanks for editing that makes more sense - the error message is telling you what Brian’s answer below is hinting at - the owners of the service would need to whitelist your domain for your code to work; the error message itself is telling you that formsubmit doesn’t support requests from AJAX, you need to POST from the backend instead

Comment: Which, admittedly, does seem to contradict their own example

Comment: So I think that's why it only works when I execute the request from their website. So I think I'll send them a message to ask them why it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

A website must allow cross origin requests to make this requests possible. The website you want to contact with ajax need https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin to be set properly.

If that's what your question was, it's not real clear what the problem here is, but maybe that answer is a hint for you.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm sorry, I had pasted the success response I get when I make the request from a console in formsubmit.co website. I already edited the post with the error response. So I think I'll send them a message to ask if their service is not accepting or what's happening.

Answer (score -1):

From your error message: "Make sure you open this page through a web server, FormSubmit will not work in pages browsed as HTML files."

It says that you need to open your webpage through a server, a live server. FormSubmit will not work in pages browsed as HTML files.

Also see at their HELP page: https://formsubmit.co/help

See this might help you fix the error.

[image: Screenshot]

You can try it on Web server like Apache HTTP server or also add an ***_url*** as a thanks page to check whether the information is posted through the action link or not.

If it is posting then it will take you to the ***_url*** page. By default, they show their own page though.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

I built [formcarry](https://formcarry.com) which is a competitor of [formsubmit](https://formsubmit.co), I can help you with that.
First, make sure that you access your page on a port like `localhost:3000` if it's something like `file://myStaticPage.html` then it won't work, you can try this [http-server](https://github.com/http-party/http-server) npm package, it's really simple to use.

If the problem continues, just use [formcarry](https://formcarry.com) and let me know if you got any errors, and I can guide you from here.